# How to check if date is valid using mktime in C?

Tags: c, date, time, scanf, mktime

I have a little problem with my code. I need to check if user's given date is valid or not. I want to check it using 2 rules:
1. Date is valid date and found in a calendar (for example 29.2.2015 is invalid because there's only 28 days in February 2015) 2. Day and month can only be max 2 numbers (for example day 10 and 02 are valid but 010 and 002 are not). All help is appreciated!

This is my code this far:

```
void dateValidator(const char *date1) {
struct tm date = {0};

int day1;
int month1;
int year1;

int vday;
int vmonth;
int vyear;

sscanf(date1, "%3d.%3d.%d",&day1,&month1,&year1);
/**How do I check that if sscanf reads more than 2 characters on month and day, date is 
invalid?**/

date.tm_year = year1 - 1900;
date.tm_mon = month1 - 1;
date.tm_mday = day1;
date.tm_isdst = -1;

vday = date.tm_mday;
vmonth = date.tm_mon;
vyear = date.tm_year;

mktime(&pvm);

if ((vday != date.tm_mday) || (vmonth != date.tm_mon) || (vyear != date.tm_year)) {
        /**This doesnt seem to work**/
        printf("Invalid date");
}
}
```

Comment: [`mktime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) does not validate ranges. October 40th is silently converted to November 9th.

Comment: Ok, so I need to check leap days and such separately?

Comment: You could "convert" with `mktime()` and check if the converted values equal the original values.

Comment: But that's what I've done there? I convert with mktime and then I check if new values equal the original values `vday != date.tm_mday`.

Comment: You used `pvm` in the call to `mktime()` and `date` in the comparisons.

Comment: pvm was typo, I changed it to date.

Comment: Also try setting the hour to 12 and `isdst` to 0.

Comment: Do not change the code/post to reflect an answer as it makes the answer invalid.  Post rolled back.

Comment: "/**This doesnt seem to work**/" --> post the examples that do not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int IsValidDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    unsigned int leap;
    unsigned char mon_day[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    /* check the rang of the year */
    if ((year < 1) || (year >= 3200))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* if it's leep year */
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
    {
        leap = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        leap = 0;
    }

    mon_day[1] += leap;

    if ((day > mon_day[month - 1]) || (day < 1))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

For ruler 1, I have wrote this code for check the date before. 
And I hope this code can help you.

The ruler 2 can easily checked, you can check it by format the valid date and compare it with the input string.

Comment: Curious, why `year >= 3200`?

Comment: BTW, `(year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))` is usually not applied to years before [1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption)

Comment: @chux, no reason `year >= 3200 ` , and you can change it.  And I don't know the leap year rule is not applied to years before 1582, you also can change it.

Comment: Note: Before 1582 a _different_ leap year rule was used,`(year % 4 == 0)`. leap year rules start about year -46 to year 12, depending on how the ancient texts are read.  Sometimes the [current leap year rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) _is_ applied far back in time, even though it does not align with what folks actually used then.

Comment: @chux, thanks, I will correct my code according to the ruler.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted my previous answer and posting another one. Actually your code is fine, You just have to send the correct parameter to `mktime` and to check its return value. I.e. change:

```
mktime(&pvm);
if ((vday != date.tm_mday) || (vmonth != date.tm_mon) || (vyear != date.tm_year)) {
    /**This doesnt seem to work**/
    printf("Invalid date");
}
```

to something like:

```
r = mktime(&date);
if (r == -1 || (vday != date.tm_mday) || (vmonth != date.tm_mon) || (vyear != date.tm_year)) {
      printf("Invalid date");
}
```

and declare the variable `r` as `time_t r;`.

Comment: Thanks for this, how did I check the other rule (max 2 numbers in a month and date)?

Comment: Adjust the second parameter of `sscanf` and check returned value.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check that if sscanf reads more than 2 characters on month and day, date is invalid?
>
> Day and month can only be max 2 <strike>numbers</strike> digits (for example day 10 and 02 are valid but 010 and 002 are not).

An easy check: Record the offset at the end of the scan and tests 1) that it is not the original `0` (scanning got that far) and 2) this is the end of the string so as to detect extra junk in `data1[]`.  Change `3d` to `2d`.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(date1, "%2d.%2d.%d %n",&day1,&month1,&year1, &n);
if (n > 0 && data1[n] == '\0') Success();
else Fail();
```

Pedantic code would check with `"%[]"` to disallow leading spaces and `'+'`.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(date1, "%*2[0-9].%*2[0-9].%*4[0-9] %n", &n);
if (n == 0 || data1[n]) Fail();
else {
  sscanf(date1, "%2d.%2d.%d",&day1,&month1,&year1);
  ...
```

> How to check if date is valid using mktime?

[@Marian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471891/2410359) posted a good solution which adds a test of the return value of `mktime()`.

```
if (-1 == mktime(&data)) Fail();
if (vday != date.tm_mday) || (vmonth != date.tm_mon) || (vyear != date.tm_year) Fail();
```